# Low Index Usage during mysqldump of InnoDB big tables

Tags: indexing, innodb, mysql

I have Nagios set up to monitor MySQL using `mysql_health` plugin ( http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/MySQL/check_mysql_health/details ). When doing `mysqldump` of big InnoDB tables (range of 50G+), I got alert about low index usage. Is there a way to disable internal stats of MySQL during dumps so it won't alert regarding index usage? I don't have indexes on these tables. These are just stat tables.

Comment: It's nagios's fault it gives you a false positive. Baron Schwartz wrote very nice post how you should monitor MySQL - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/22/how-to-monitor-mysql-with-perconas-nagios-plugins/  . I'd suggest to monitor query execution time, because it correlates with an SLA. Check more details in my post https://twindb.com/about-nagios-best-practices/

Comment: Low index usage in database is not a false positive.